# What type of visa should a non EU national apply for, for an unpaid one month internship at a private company in Belgium?

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium, syrian-citizens, work-permit

A 22 year old student who just graduated will join a private company in Belgium for a one month unpaid internship/training.
The company did not provide any information or help regarding the visa he needs to apply for. Instead they said "Please check what is feasible on your side" (visa, accommodation etc.).

Could it be that he just needs to apply for a tourist visa, and join them casually?

Any guidance or info before he gets back to the company asking for info? I was expecting them to apply for a work permit for him (http://werk-economie-emploi.brussels/en/work-permit-intern).

Comment: What is the student’s citizenship?

Comment: He is Syrian with permanent residency in Lebanon

Comment: One month is certainly short enough for this to be on-topic here, no reason to move to Expatriates - the question is certainly not about “ immigration or moving **for extended periods of time**”.

Comment: @Postscripter I don’t have the knowledge to tell you what the requirements are, but I’m pretty certain a tourist visa is not suitable. Beyond that, if the company is unwilling to assist with things like this I would have serious doubts about how good an idea it is to work with them at all. Unpaid internships are frankly exploitative at the best of times, if they won’t even help with the visa process they clearly have no desire to ensure this experience goes well for the intern.